# Would Spark perform better than Hadoop MapReduce if running on low memory?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce

Understanding MapReduce and Spark, the major difference turns out that Spark requires less I/O due to maintaining "narrow" lineage *i.e.* taking the input on one worker, multiple partitions per worker, processing it and moving along in the lineage rather than performing one job of the map and then flushing on the disk and then performing the other consequential job. In a concise manner, Spark is HDFS->read->map and Hadoop MapReduce is HDFS->read->map->HDFS.

Understandable, MapReduce was more than five years older than Spark and could not have a design that leverages the system's memory.

I want to understand whether running Spark on low memory would be the same as running a MapReduce?

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing I/O with memory requirements. Mapreduce would still allocate YARN containers of a certain size. If you want to accurately compare, you'd have to run Spark on YARN

Comment: I meant if the memory is size is low, Spark cannot leverage the memory, right? It would be spilling to disk all the time?

Comment: Really depends on the type of application you want to run. For a text classification problem, for example, Spark will surely perform better/faster than Hadoop (mainly because Spark has so many optimised tools in its libraries) even at a moderate low memory, because Spark during execution chooses to store data in disk only as the _last resort_.

Comment: What would you make out of the PageRank algorithm for differentiating Spark on low memory v/s MapReduce?

Comment: I don't think algorithm matters here. Again, though, Spark GraphX / Graphframes already has a pagerank algorithm